# Android SeekBar is Hiding in Landscape Screen

Tags: java, android, view, screen, landscape

I have a button and seekbar in activity. First case the button is visible and the seekbar is invisible. When I press the button seekbar is visible so far so clear. The problem is When I press the button and seekbar is visible in portrait screen later, when turn screen to landscape the seekbar is invisible. How to visible the seekbar in landscape screen?

```
    Button btn;
    SeekBar seekbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);

    seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekbar.setVisibility(seekbar.INVISIBLE);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            seekbar.setVisibility(seekbar.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by adding the `android:configChanges` node to your Activity's manifest node

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

or for Android 3.2 (API level 13) and newer:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` is worked
`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` not worked.
thanks.